# Images are not being fetched from Strapi backend and all other data fields are being fetched properly

Tags: image, next.js, fetch, strapi, cloudinary

I am developing an Ap using nextjs as frontend and strapi as backend. home page works fine with the products being rendered with the thumbnail and all related fields i.e. title subtitle price etc.. life is good

but when i click on an individual product the page loads with all data except the images i.e. no thumbnail no remaining images.

I have been getting some cannot fetch data errors and looking through online i tried to downgrade my node js hopping it resolves the issue while the cannot fetch errors r gone the outcome is still the same even after downgrading node js all it did is removed the error and the data displayed is still everything except the images

next js front end
strapi backend
cloudinary.com to store my assets

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_GYyOijWBc and at 2:26:17 when he does the same fetch on insomnia he is getting the images too hence in his tutorial when he maps the images they show up and i have done the same thing step by step still nothing

This is what i get when i try to fetch data from the backend via insomnia the thumbnail is there still not shown and the remaining images aren't even being fetched

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 6,
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Air Jordan 13 Retro",
            "subtitle": "Men's Shoes",
            "price": 349,
            "description": "\"The Air Jordan 13 Retro brings back the memorable game shoe that Michael Jordan wore during the '97–98 season, all the way to his 6th championship title. All the classic details are there like the quilted overlay, iconic sculpted midsole and holographic eye.\n\n- Colour Shown: Black/White/True Red\n- Style: 414571-062\"",
            "size": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "size": "UK 6",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 6.5",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 7",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 7.5",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 8",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 8.5",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 9",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 9.5",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 10",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 10.5",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 11",
                        "enabled": false
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "UK 11.5",
                        "enabled": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            "original_price": null,
            "slug": "air-jordan-13-retro",
            "createdAt": "2023-04-24T20:04:41.805Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-28T11:20:43.351Z",
            "publishedAt": "2023-04-28T11:20:42.084Z",
            "thumbnail": {
                "data": {
                    "id": 418,
                    "attributes": {
                        "name": "thumbnail.webp",
                        "alternativeText": null,
                        "caption": null,
                        "width": 592,
                        "height": 592,
                        "formats": {
                            "small": {
                                "ext": ".webp",
                                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/djpsxkial/image/upload/v1682680818/small_thumbnail_5dd7b30f21.webp",
                                "hash": "small_thumbnail_5dd7b30f21",
                                "mime": "image/webp",
                                "name": "small_thumbnail.webp",
                                "path": null,
                                "size": 9.79,
                                "width": 500,
                                "height": 500,
                                "provider_metadata": {
                                    "public_id": "small_thumbnail_5dd7b30f21",
                                    "resource_type": "image"
                                }
                            },
                            "thumbnail": {
                                "ext": ".webp",
                                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/djpsxkial/image/upload/v1682680816/thumbnail_thumbnail_5dd7b30f21.webp",
                                "hash": "thumbnail_thumbnail_5dd7b30f21",
                                "mime": "image/webp",
                                "name": "thumbnail_thumbnail.webp",
                                "path": null,
                                "size": 1.77,
                                "width": 156,
                                "height": 156,
                                "provider_metadata": {
                                    "public_id": "thumbnail_thumbnail_5dd7b30f21",
                                    "resource_type": "image"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "hash": "thumbnail_5dd7b30f21",
                        "ext": ".webp",
                        "mime": "image/webp",
                        "size": 15.46,
                        "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/djpsxkial/image/upload/v1682680816/thumbnail_5dd7b30f21.webp",
                        "previewUrl": null,
                        "provider": "cloudinary",
                        "provider_metadata": {
                            "public_id": "thumbnail_5dd7b30f21",
                            "resource_type": "image"
                        },
                        "createdAt": "2023-04-28T11:20:18.655Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2023-04-28T11:20:18.655Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            "categories": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "attributes": {
                            "name": "Jordan",
                            "slug": "jordan",
                            "createdAt": "2023-04-24T18:51:53.260Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-04-24T18:52:10.408Z",
                            "publishedAt": "2023-04-24T18:52:10.042Z"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "attributes": {
                            "name": "Men's Shoes",
                            "slug": "men-s-shoes",
                            "createdAt": "2023-04-24T23:34:45.199Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-04-24T23:34:55.631Z",
                            "publishedAt": "2023-04-24T23:34:55.250Z"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],
"meta": {
    "pagination": {
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 25,
        "pageCount": 1,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

}

This is the product slug

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Wrapper from "@/components/Wrapper";
import { IoMdHeartEmpty } from "react-icons/io";
import ProductDetailsCarousel from "@/components/ProductDetailsCarousel";
// import RelatedProducts from "@/components/RelatedProducts";
import { fetchDataFromApi } from "@/utils/api";
import { getDiscountedPercentage } from "@/utils/helper";

const ProductDetails = ({ product, products }) => {
  const [selectedSize, setSelectedSize] = useState();
  const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
  const p = product?.data?.[0]?.attributes;

  return (
    <div className="w-full md:py-20">
      <Wrapper>
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row md:px-10 gap-[50px] lg:gap-[100px]">
          {/* left column start */}
          <div className="w-full md:w-auto flex-[1.5] max-w-[500px] lg:max-w-full mx-auto lg:mx-0">
            <ProductDetailsCarousel images={p.image?.data} />
          </div>
          {/* left column end */}

          {/* right column start */}
          <div className="flex-[1] py-3">
            {/* Product Title */}
            <div className="text-[34px] font-semibold mb-2 leading-tight">
              {p.name}
            </div>
            {/* Product Subtitle */}
            <div className="text-lg font-semibold mb-5">{p.subtitle}</div>
            {/* Product Price */}
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <p className="mr-2 text-lg font-semibold">MRP : ${p.price}</p>
              {p.original_price && (
                <>
                  <p className="text-base font-medium line-through">
                    $;{p.original_price}
                  </p>
                  <p className="ml-auto text-base font-medium text-green-500">
                    {getDiscountedPercentage(p.original_price, p.price)}% off
                  </p>
                </>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="text-md font-medium text-black/[0.5]">
              incl. of taxes
            </div>
            <div className="text-md font-medium text-black/[0.5] mb-20">
              {`(Also includes all applicable duties)`}
            </div>
            {/* Product Size Range Start */}
            <div className="mb-10">
              {/* Heading Start */}
              <div className="flex justify-between mb-2">
                <div className="text-md font-semibold">Select Size</div>
                <div className="text-md font-medium text-black/[0.5] cursor-pointer">
                  Select Guide
                </div>
              </div>
              {/* Heading end */}

              {/* Size Selection Start */}

              <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2">
                {p.size.data.map((item, i) => (
                  <div
                    key={i}
                    className={`border rounded-md text-center py-3 font-medium ${
                      item.enabled
                        ? "hover:border-black cursor-pointer"
                        : "cursor-not-allowed bg-black/[0.1] opacity-50"
                    }`}
                    onClick={() => {
                      setSelectedSize(item.size);
                      setShowError(false);
                    }}
                  >
                    {item.size}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>

              {/* Size Selection end */}

              {/* Show Error Msg Start */}

              {showError && (
                <div className="text-red-600 mt-1">
                  Size Selection is Required
                </div>
              )}

              {/* Show Error Msg end */}
            </div>
            {/* Product Size Range end */}
            {/* Add to Cart Button Start */}
            <button className="w-full py-4 rounded-full bg-black text-white text-lg font-medium transition-transform active:scale-95 mb-3 hover:opacity-75">
              Add to Cart
            </button>
            {/* Add to Cart Button end */}
            {/* WishList Button Start */}
            <button className="w-full py-4 rounded-full border hover:border-black text-lg font-medium transition-transform active:scale-95 flex items-center justify-center gap-2 hover:opacity-75 mb-10">
              Wishlist
              <IoMdHeartEmpty size={20} />
            </button>
            {/* * WishList Button end * */}
            <div>
              <div className="text-lg font-bold mb-5">Product Details</div>
              <div className="text-md mb-5">
                Ready to excite? Celebrating Serena's penchant for flair
                (specifically that on-court, denim skirt moment), this fresh
                take on on the coveted hoops icon flawlessly blends fashion with
                sport. From the raw-edged, hemp upper to the metallic lace hooks
                to the Swoosh, you'll be sure to awe the crowd with these
                denim-inspired details.
              </div>
              <div className="text-md mb-5">
                Ready to excite? Celebrating Serena's penchant for flair
                (specifically that on-court, denim skirt moment), this fresh
                take on on the coveted hoops icon flawlessly blends fashion with
                sport. From the raw-edged, hemp upper to the metallic lace hooks
                to the Swoosh, you'll be sure to awe the crowd with these
                denim-inspired details.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* right column start */}
        </div>
        {/* <RelatedProducts /> */}
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const products = await fetchDataFromApi("/api/products?populate=*");

  const paths = products?.data?.map((p) => ({
    params: {
      slug: p.attributes.slug,
    },
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  const product = await fetchDataFromApi(
    `/api/products?populate=*&filters[slug][$eq]=${slug}`
  );
  const products = await fetchDataFromApi(
    `/api/products?populate=*&[filters][slug][$ne]=${slug}`
  );

  return {
    props: {
      product,
      products,
    },
  };
}
```

This the ProductDetailsCarousel

```
import React from "react";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";

const ProductDetailsCarousel = ({ images }) => {
  return (
    <div className="text-white text-[20px] w-full max-w-[1360px] mx-auto sticky top-[50px]">
      <Carousel
        infiniteLoop={true}
        showIndicators={false}
        showStatus={false}
        thumbWidth={60}
        className="productCarousel"
      >
        {images?.map((img) => (
          <img
            key={img.id}
            src={img.attributes.url}
            alt={img.attributes.name}
          />
        ))}
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetailsCarousel;
```

The url.js in utils

```
export const STRAPI_API_TOKEN = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_TOKEN;

export const API_URL =
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || "http://127.0.0.1:1337";
```

The api.js in utils

```
import { API_URL, STRAPI_API_TOKEN } from "./urls.";

export const fetchDataFromApi = async (endpoint) => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + STRAPI_API_TOKEN,
    },
  };

  const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}${endpoint}`, options);
  const data = await res.json();

  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

well after all the hassle i went through i solved the error. in strapi when creating the slug for some reason ( not sure i chose this option but maybe ) the image was saved as a private field in the advanced tab. i unchecked it, saved and all works fine now the images are being displayed properly